# What is my best bet on periodically running a task to update Live Activity when my app is in the background?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an idea for an app that utilises Live Activities, inspired by the Flightly app (it starts a Live Activity for a plane ride): Basically I wanna use open data from an HTTP endpoint that is reachable via the onboard WiFi on a bus. E.g. you board the bus, connect to the onboard WiFi, open the app, it fetches details about the stops and then you start a Live Activity guiding you to a selected stop. So far so good. But sometimes the bus faces delays, etc. In that case, I need to update the Live Activity. That is easy when my app is running. It is not so easy, when my app is not running (or running in the background).

What is my best approach to regularly fetching data from the endpoint and updating my Live Activity? The problem is, that the endpoint is only reachable on the buses WiFi. So it looks like I cannot use APNS to push updates to the Live Activity (since my service running outside the bus cannot access the endpoint that provides the details and thus cannot push any meaningful updates). Background Tasks (e.g. background app refresh) run infrequently.

What options are left? I thought about receiving location updates in the background and acting on them to update my app state (and possible the Live Activity, if needed), although I haven't investigated that path in detail, yet.

Has anybody faced a similar issue and found a solution or can provide some guidance on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Background Task is another approach but they are not guaranteed.

Comment: It sounds like significant location change might work

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option is core location. So keep your application running by monitoring the position and then you can update the Live Activity by fetching the information from your access point. It should be fine for app review since you could use the the location to show a position on a map and only while the person is on the bus.

If your application isn't running you have to send the ActivityAttributes via APNS. Since the data cannot be accessed from a remote server that would communicate with APNS there is no direct way to use ActivityKit push notifications. An indirect approach (which I would not recommend) would be to send silent push notifications triggers every 5min or so and fetch the newest information when the application is woken up. But this won't work when the app is force-quit and using silent pushes to trigger polling will give you a bad score by the system and eventually the frequency will be throttled from APNS.